# How to Apply the GROUP BY in this instance

Tags: sql

I have a query which has this column as one of the columns  in the select list

```
isnull((SELECT sum(bi.PROGRESS_BIL + bi.HARD_BIL + bi.SOFT_BIL + bi.FEES_BIL + bi.OAFEE_BIL + bi.RETAINER_BIL + bi.PREMDISC_BIL - bi.CREDIT_TOT)
FROM bo_Live5.dbo.BLT_BILLM bi
WHERE bi.MATTER_UNO = m.MATTER_UNO), 0) AS billings_to_date
```

I want to know how to apply this in the GROUP BY

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried dropping that whole honking thing into the group by?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You would using a subquery:

```
select billings_to_date, . . .
from (select isnull((SELECT sum(bi.PROGRESS_BIL + bi.HARD_BIL + bi.SOFT_BIL + bi.FEES_BIL + bi.OAFEE_BIL + bi.RETAINER_BIL + bi.PREMDISC_BIL - bi.CREDIT_TOT)
                     FROM bo_Live5.dbo.BLT_BILLM bi
                     WHERE bi.MATTER_UNO = m.MATTER_UNO
                    ), 0
                   ) AS billings_to_date
       from . . .
      ) t
group by billings_to_date;
```